# Copy data from closed workbook and paste if they data in common

Tags: vba, excel

I am a trainee in a company and basically became tech support (better than coffee maker though)
And so i'm trying to get one closed workbook to copy data into an open one
So far this is the code i've got but i've some troubles with the if statement

```
Sub allergo()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim bkBk1 As Workbook, wkBk2 As Workbook
    Dim wkSht As Object
    Dim mnt As String
    lr = wkBk2.Sheets(1).Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    mnt = InputBox("Enter Filename")
    Set wkBk1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wkBk2 = Workbooks.Open("Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx")

    For Each cell In wkBk1.Sheets(1).Range(wkBk1.Sheets(1).Cells(2, "R"), wkBk1.Sheets(1).Cells(lr, "R"))

    wkBk1.Sheets(1).Range("R1:R" & lr).Value = wkBk2.Sheets(1).Range("R1:R" & lastRow).Value

    wkBk2.Close
End Sub
```

Basically I've got two files that have the same columns but between some weeks rows disapear or appear as each row is a purchase order with a specific number and in row R we add comments and i want the comments in column R to copy to the new work book on the row where there's the same purchase order number. While some comments are attached to purchase orders that are not in the file anymore so they are not needed and some purchase orders have moved so i can't just copy paste.
Not sure the If is a good idea as it won't compare my row E 146 with all the others of the new work book and thus only test E146 closed workbook = E146 newworkbook while it should test E146 closed = E147/E148 etc..

This is the closed workbook:
[image: The closed workbook]

This is the new workbook:
[image: The new workbook]

Thanks for the help !

Maybe a VLOOKUP is possible for this kind of things i'm not sure ..

```
Sub strilltrying()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
Dim lr As Long
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row



Cells(lr, "R").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(E2,'H:\Documents\[OPEN ORDERS 16.07.2018.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$E:$R,14)"


End Sub
```

This is the vlookup formula that works but not fully as i've to take two different variables.. I found that index + match can do it but i'm having a hard time figuring it out.
I'd need an index formula that compares column E and column J in the way of the vlookup.

Comment: what `if` statement?

Comment: you could just put in formulas to do this?

Comment: There's none in it since i don't know how to put it in there..

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub allergo()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim bkBk1 As Workbook, wkBk2 As Workbook
Dim wkSht As Object
Dim mnt As String
lr = wkBk2.Sheets(1).Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
mnt = InputBox("Enter Filename")
Set wkBk1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wkBk2 = Workbooks.Open("Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx")

For Each cell In wkBk1.Sheets(1).Range(wkBk1.Sheets(1).Cells(2, "R"), wkBk1.Sheets(1).Cells(lr, "R"))
if cell = "" then 'add your clause here
wkBk1.Sheets(1).Range("R1:R" & lr).Value = wkBk2.Sheets(1).Range("R1:R" & lastRow).Value

end if
next cell
wkBk2.Close
End Sub
```

Your requirements are not entirely clear, I would avoid a loop if possible as well.

Comment: I added pictures to make it more clear , so i need to copy paste the comment from the first to the second and have them in the right place and if one line disappeared since the order is not there anymore i want the code to do nothing